# Use of xarray to combine two data arrays

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am using xarray to interpolate a given data set and it works fine.

Here is the result:
[interp()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjyP6.png)

Then when I try to update the interpolated array into an empty array of the same resolution, I am getting a blank array and data is not copied.

```
#odimx,odimy=560
cx = isocenter['x'] - (odimx)*0.1/2.0) 
cz = isocenter['z'] - (odimy)*0.1/2.0) 
fin_ax=[]
fin_az=[]
for i in range(odimx):
    fin_ax.append(cx + i * 0.1)
for i in range(odimy):
    fin_az.append(cz + i * 0.1)
beam_data = xr.DataArray(np.zeros((odimx,odimy),dtype=np.float), dims = ('x','z'), coords ={'x':fin_az,'z':fin_ax})
beam_data.combine_first(new_lines)
```

[combine_first()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5eoU.png)

I need the last step because I have to compare two arrays to get my result and am trying to interpolate the smaller grid(step 1 using interp() which worked) and make it the same size as the reference grid(combine_first() - did not work). Thank you for reading this question! Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be that `combine_first` is not an in-place operation?

```
beam_data = beam_data.combine_first(new_lines)
```